# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' to data type int

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2014

I have a query that is getting some that is comparing a uniqueidentifier in the table and its a strange one.

```
SELECT *  FROM   vw_ryzex_CustomerAssets where BillToId='51ee47d2-eb97-4b12-8865-dab9a7f15a46'
```

So when i run this query i get the following error
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' to data type int.

But when i select only the top 1000 i get the result and no error occurrs I tried Casting and converting checking nulls everything i could i tried following queries but did not work

```
SELECT * FROM   vw_ryzex_CustomerAssets_V2 where CAST(BillToId as nvarchar(200))=Cast('51ee47d2-eb97-4b12-8865-dab9a7f15a46' as nvarchar(200))

SELECT * FROM   vw_ryzex_CustomerAssets where (Case BillToId 
                                                when '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' Then NEWID()
                                       ELSE BillToId
                                                END) = '51ee47d2-eb97-4b12-8865-dab9a7f15a46'
```

Can anyone help me on this please..?

This is the view definition

```
 ALTER VIEW [dbo].[vw_ryzex_CustomerAssets_V2] AS SELECT a.Id,
     '~/Reports/BillToAssetDetails.aspx?btid='
     + CONVERT(VARCHAR(256), a.BillToId)
     + '&vidx=1&caid='
     + CONVERT(VARCHAR(256), a.Id)                                     AS URL,
     '~/Reports/BillToAssets.aspx?btid='
     + CONVERT(VARCHAR(256), a.BillToId)
     + '&vidx=1&caid='
     + CONVERT(VARCHAR(256), a.Id)                                     AS EditUrl,
     LEFT(a.PartDescription, 50)                                       AS PartDescription,-- EKL:03042009  
     a.Quantity,
     a.SerialNumber,
     /*    CASE ISNULL(s.Name,'') WHEN '' THEN a.Location ELSE s.Name + '(' + s.ErpId + ')  
     '+ a.Location END AS Location, */
     a.Location,
     s.NAME + '(' + s.ErpId + ')'                                      AS SiteName,
     --a.OrderId,   
     o.OrderGroupId                                                    AS OrderId,
     a.OrderErpId,
     a.OrderExt,
     a.OrderLine,
     a.DateCreated,
     a.DateModified,
     Isnull(ru.DisplayName, '')                                        AS ModifiedBy,
     a.BillToId,
     a.PartNo,
     b.NAME                                                            AS BillToName,
     b.Description                                                     AS BillToDescription,
     b.ErpId                                                           AS BillToErpId,
     b.DateCreated                                                     AS BillToDateCreated,
     b.DateModified                                                    AS BillToDateModified,
     b.ModifiedBy                                                      AS BillToModifiedBy,
     a.ProductId,
     --p.ProductPartNo,   
     --p.ProductModel,   
     --p.ProductDescription as ProductDescription,  
     --p.ProductDateCreated,   
     --p.ProductDateModified,   
     --p.ProductModifiedBy,   
     Isnull(ol.UnitPrice, '0')                                         AS UnitPrice,
     ol.SalesTax,
     Isnull(ol.TotalPrice, '0')                                        AS TotalPrice,
     ol.OrderErpId                                                     AS OrderLineId,
     Isnull(ol.QuantityOrdered, '0')                                   AS QuantityOrdered,
     Isnull(ol.QuantityShipped, '0')                                   AS QuantityShipped,
     -- o.Created AS OrderDate,                                                           
     Dateadd(mi, Datediff(mi, Getutcdate(), Getdate()), o.Created)     AS OrderDate,
     -- o.ShippedDate AS ShipDate,   
     Dateadd(mi, Datediff(mi, Getutcdate(), Getdate()), o.ShippedDate) AS ShipDate,
     o.SalesPersonName                                                 AS SalesPersonDisplayName,
     o.BillingCurrency                                                 AS Currency,
     dbo.vw_PurchaseOrderPayments.PurchaseOrderPaymentNumber           AS CustPo,
     a.AssetNumber,
     a.CustomerReference,
     a.ModelNumber,
     a.CustomField1Value                                               AS xCust1,
     a.CustomField2Value                                               AS xCust2,
     s.Id                                                              AS ShipToId,
     s.AddressLine1                                                    AS Address1,
     s.AddressLine2                                                    AS Address2,
     s.AddressLine3                                                    AS Address3,
     s.City,
     s.Country,
     s.[State],
     s.ZipCode                                                         AS Zip 
FROM   dbo.vw_PurchaseOrderPayments
     RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.vw_PurchaseOrders AS o
                   ON dbo.vw_PurchaseOrderPayments.OrderFormId = o.OrderFormId -- EKL:03042009 chg from OrderGroupId to OrderFormId  
     RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.ryzex_CustomerAsset AS a
                      INNER JOIN dbo.ryzex_BillTo AS b WITH (NOLOCK)
                              ON a.BillToId = b.Id
                                 AND Isnull(a.Inactive, 0) = 0
                      LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ryzex_ShipTo AS s WITH (NOLOCK)
                                   ON a.ShipToId = s.Id
                                      AND b.Id = s.BillToId
                      LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ryzex_Product AS p WITH (NOLOCK)
                                   ON a.PartNo = p.ProductPartNo
                      LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.vw_OrderLines AS ol
                                   ON a.OrderErpId = ol.OrderErpId
                                      AND a.OrderLine = ol.LineNumber
                   ON o.OrderErpNumber = a.OrderErpId
                      AND o.OrderExtensionNumber = a.OrderExt
     LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ryzex_Users AS ru WITH (NOLOCK)
                  ON a.ModifiedBy = ru.Id
```

The BillToId that is coming from ryzex_CustomerAsset tbl is a not null uniqueidentifier

Comment: we need to see the code of your view

Comment: The comparison in the `WHERE` is not the problem.  The view definition is the problem.

Comment: Just added the view.. @GordonLinoff

Comment: Added view @Lamak

Comment: jeezus, that view uses so many other views....

Comment: But does it matter though cause the BillToId i am pulling is from a table ryzex_CustomerAsset..

Comment: it matter because the problem is with the whole view. Most likely, if you do a `SELECT * FROM view` with no filters whatsoever, you'll still get an error. That's because there's a problem somewhere in the code of your view

Comment: What datatype is the `id` column of the `ryzex_BillTo` table?

Comment: Its the same UniqueIdentifier and not null

Comment: Unfortunately, we can't really help you that much, I can start asking what datatype each column is, and then start analyzing the code of the other views, etc. It's a guessing game for us

Comment: It's hard to understand which record of your view causing error. try to use binary search concept to dig your error.